# How to authedmine.com mining 24/7? (Coinhive)

Tags: javascript, coin-hive

I'm using Coinhive for the first time. I setup the JS on my website. When I click on the "Open" miner link in my Dashboard, it brings me to a simple page that displays the hashing/mining happening in real-time. This is great but when I close the authedmine browser tab, the JS stops mining across all browsers instantly.

My question is: Do I need to keep this authedmine.com tab open 24/7 for mining to persist?? That seems a little crazy. Am I missing something here? **How do I continue mining XMR after I close the authedmine tab?**

Answer (score 2):

Coinhive is a javascript-based miner. Since Javascript is web-based, you have to keep the page open in order for it to stay active.

Answer (score 1):

How do I continue mining XMR after I close the authedmine tab?...answer: you dont.

besides that: it takes forever to mine even as low as 0.001 xmr.

i would suggest to start mining in a different way.
I am currently mining on www.moneromahaz.com..new poolsite
(look at: Get started.

Comment: I mean if you have enough users on your site this can be viable. It's considered an alternative to ads